# Reloading gsp in deployed application with Grails 4/5

Tags: grails

For many years I have been using the handy facility to be able to make tweaks to GSP files in deployed Grails 2 applications, with `grails.gsp.enable.reload = true` in config.groovy.

It seems this facility is still here in Grails 4 and now 5, according to the [docs](https://gsp.grails.org/latest/guide/makingChangesToADeployedApplication.html). But I cannot get it to work. In Grails 2, the GSPs were available in `WEB-INF/grails-app/views`, no such directory is present on a deployed Grails 4 or 5 app.

Does this actually work still? Is there some other step I have to do?

Comment: Have you assigned a custom value to `grails.gsp.view.dir`?

Comment: No I haven't, yet. With Grails 2 this was not necessary, and according to the Grails 5 docs it still isn't: "Setting "grails.gsp.view.dir" is optional. If it’s not specified, you can update files directly to the application server’s deployed war directory." It's the bit about updating files directly to the application server’s deployed war directory which I'm having problems with (which I didn't with Grails 2).

Comment: I understand what our docs say.  I wanted to know if you had assigned a custom value to `grails.gsp.view.dir` as a matter of troubleshooting, not to suggest you did something wrong.  I am sorry for the confusion.  Best of luck!

Comment: I don't think there's any confusion, is there? It appears to me that something which was previously working in Grails 2 is no longer working in Grails 4/5. I will try setting `grails.gsp.view.dir` and seeing if it helps diagnose the issue. But ultimately I do still want to be able to update files directly in the deployed war directory.

Comment: "I don't think there's any confusion" - The confusion was mine.  Apologies.

Comment: I guess you didn't find a solution to this? I have also been using it in Grails 2 & will be missing it in Grails 4+.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, configuring "grails.gsp.view.dir" enables GSP reloading. So instead of relying on "WEB-INF/grails-app/views" you just have to handle the source directory yourself. Note to self (and others): Add a trailing slash when configuring this directory!